# при нажатие на BackButton не позволить фрагменту вернуться назад

Tags: java, android

здравствуйте ,что надо добавить в метод `onBackPressed()` в `MainActivity` чтобы невозможно было при нажатие на `BackButton` вернуться назад с фрагмента ?

в `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

переход на фрагмент

```
protected Fragment fragment = null;
/**
* Call to LoadingGame fragment
*/
public void LoadingGamePath() {
    fragment = new LoadingFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: у меня есть фрагмент игры мне надо чтобы пользователь не мог выйти с этого окна при нажатии на кнопку назад на телефоне

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `MainActivity` переопределите метод `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_body);

    if (!(fragment instanceof LoadingFragment)) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Тогда кнопка `back` не будет реагировать на нажатие, только в том случае, если она нажата в тот момент, когда в контейнере находится фрагмент `LoadingFragment`.

Comment: ок но тогда не имеет значение из какого класса  backbutton не работает

Comment: @DavidKern, Обновил ответ.

Comment: ок работает спасибо очень помогли закреплю эту тему :)))

Answer (score 1):

Переопределить метод onBackPressed. Уберите вызов метода super.onBackPresed

Comment: а куда метод переопределить ?

Comment: В фрагменте его переопределите

Comment: @pavel163, А у фрагмента есть такой метод?

Comment: нету %$^%$^%$^%^%$^

Comment: я кидал в фрагмент он удаляет  @Override и ничего не происходит